# My tick method is messed up

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I created a class called Bullets:

```
public class Bullets {

private double x;
private double y;
private BufferedImage bulletImage;
Bullets(double x, double y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(loader.loadImage("/Pics/TheSpriteSheet.png"));
    bulletImage = ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(bulletImage, (int)x, (int)y, null);
}
public void tick(){
    y--;
}
}
```

Then I created a class called BulletQualities:

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class BulletQualities {
Bullets b;
private LinkedList<Bullets> bulletList = new LinkedList<Bullets>();

public void addBullet(Bullets b){
    bulletList.add(b);
}
public void tick(){
    for(int x = 0;x <= bulletList.size();x++){
```

I get an error on this line

```
        bulletList.get(x).tick();
    }
}
public void render(Graphics g){
    for(int x = 0;x <= bulletList.size(); x++){
        bulletList.get(x).render(g);
    }
}
public void removeBullet(Bullets bullet){
bulletList.remove(bullet);
}
}
```

Then, in my Game class I did this:

```
Bullets b = new Bullets(playerClass.getX(), playerClass.getY());
BulletQualities bulletQualities = new BulletQualities();
public void init(){
    bulletQualities.addBullet(b);
}
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    playerClass.render(g);
    bulletQualities.render(g);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void tick(){
    playerClass.tick();
```

I get an error on this line

```
    bulletQualities.tick();
}
```

The exact error I get is this:

Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
    at mainPackage.BulletQualities.tick(BulletQualities.java:15)
    at mainPackage.Game.tick(Game.java:105)
    at mainPackage.Game.run(Game.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the list only upto size-1 index. So change this:

```
for(int x = 0;x <= bulletList.size();x++){
```

to

```
for(int x = 0;x < bulletList.size();x++){
```

List internally stores element in an array and an array contains element from 0th index to upto its size-1 index.
Anytime you will try to get bulletList.get(x) where x= size of list, it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

There are better way to iterate list in Java verion 5.0 and abaove. Using enhanced `for` loop, you will never run into such situation. Here is how you can transform your code using enhanced `for` loop:

```
for(Bullets bullet:bulletList){
    bullet.tick();
}
```

Comment: @LtLobster:- If the answer helped you then you can accept the answer. (A right tick mark which turns green when clicked) as it helps others facing the same issue in future